# PostgreSQL:Failed to obtain JDBC Connection

Tags: java, postgresql, spring

Я пытаюсь подключить базу данных PostgreSQL к Spring. При конфигурации напрямую в Config все работает, но если использую файла конфигурации, получаю ошибку:

```
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: �����: ������������ "sosni" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: �����: ������������ "sosni" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: �����: ������������ "sosni" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:83)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:465)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:475)
    com.sosnilosm.springapp.dao.CustomerDAO.selectAllCustomers(CustomerDAO.java:35)
    com.sosnilosm.springapp.controllers.CustomersController.index(CustomersController.java:30)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: �����: ������������ "sosni" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:659)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:180)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
    org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:247)
    org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)
    org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)
    java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:683)
    java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:191)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:155)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:465)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:475)
    com.sosnilosm.springapp.dao.CustomerDAO.selectAllCustomers(CustomerDAO.java:35)
    com.sosnilosm.springapp.controllers.CustomersController.index(CustomersController.java:30)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Мой Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.sosnilosm</groupId>
  <artifactId>firstMvcApplication</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>firstMvcApplication Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.springframework.version>5.3.23</org.springframework.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.15.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>firstMvcApplication</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Config

```java
package com.sosnilosm.springapp.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.postgresql.jdbc2.optional.PoolingDataSource;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * @author Sergei Sosnilo
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.sosnilosm.springapp")
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private final Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext, Environment environment) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("driver")));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }
}
```

database.properties

```java
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db
username=postgres
password=3647
```

P.S.: Проблема решилась сама собой после перезагрузки ноутбука. Тем ни менее, оставлю вопрос открытым, т.к. надеюсь найти альтернативное, более надежное, решение проблемы

Comment: у меня подобная ошибка, только с моим логином выходит. перезагрузка пк не помогла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.getProperty("user.name") returns HOSTNAME instead of currently logged username

**username**=postgres
usernameForDB=postgres

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Твое приложение не может подключиться к базе данных из-за неверных данных для подключения. Попробуй значения из properties в консоль вывести и увидишь, что вместо  `username=postgres` у тебя `username=sosni`. Изменение `username` на `user` решит проблему

Answer (score 0):

по какой-то причине environment берёт имя пользователя из системы , а не из файла database.properties
Даже если прописать :

```
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/first_db
user=postgres
password=postgres
```

но в bean вписать :

```
dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("user"));
dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("password"));
System.out.println(environment.getProperty("username"));
```

в консоли выведет не null , а имя пользователя системы (по крайней мере у меня так получилось)
решение , как и описывалось выше - не использовать слово username для обозначения имени пользователя.